# Why doesn't my arduino button work on ports other than 0 and 1?

Tags: c++, arduino, hardware, arduino-c++

I have a button that turns on a LED but it only works when I assign the button the port 0 and 1. If I try port 2 it doesn't work. Therefore I am only able to use two buttons. On the board 0 and 1 seems to be special compared to the other ones. How do I get around that to be able to use the other ports?

Comment: Have you tried ports other than port 2? Also, could you post your code so we can more easily answer the question?

Comment: What arduino?  There are more than 30 different boards. 
 Please show a [mcve]

Comment: Did you set the pinMode?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple program that models what I think you were describing.

In your code, if you want to turn on an LED when you press a button:

- You need to make sure that the LED pin is set to output.
- The button pin needs to be set to input.

sample program:

```
#define LED 13
#define BUTTON 5
void setup()
{
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(BUTTON, INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  if ( digitalRead(BUTTON) )
  {
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
  }
}
```

Regarding the circuit,

- you need to have a current limiting resistor in series with the LED.
- make sure the LED is facing the right way.
- The button needs to be connected from +5V to the button pin.
- You need to have a pulldown resistor between the button pin and ground.